# How can array elements be accessed in separate files

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would take up 2 javscript files.

In one file i declare an array of 5 elements.

Can anyone tell me how can i retrieve those array elements in another file.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose one js file name `script1.js` and another `script2.js`

**script1.js**

```
var ar=["1","2"];
```

**script2.js**

```
console.log(ar);
```

in your html file place your first script file before 2nd script file

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

sample.js

```
var a = new a();
function a()
{
    this.array = [1,2,3];
}
```

sample2.js

```
function b()
{
    alert(a.array);
}
```

sample1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "sample.js"></script>
        <script src = "sample2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> b();</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```